# although I have changed username in control panel still getting same name in cmd echo "%USERNAME% in window 10 (Re-started laptop)

Tags: windows, hadoop

Scenario : i am trying to work on hadoop its giving class not found . and the issue is i have space in user name .
[Snap_of_issue_while_using_hadoop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtPNy.png)

Problem : I want to change my username from "Moin Khan" to "Moin"

Tried method :
Control panel -> user accounts -> Change you account name -> edited new name as "Moin"

I have re-started laptop still I am getting %USERNAME% as "Moin Khan"

[Name_in_windows_account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlKo1.png)

[Wrong_output_in_cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwDUj.png)

Comment: Hadoop isn't really supported on Windows and you're really not going to have much luck using the Windows shell. If you really want to use Hadoop then I'd suggest looking at a sandbox VM or Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your Windows username doesn't retroactively change `C:\Users` folder, which is the problem.

One solution - Move hadoop files to `C:\hadoop\bin` + `C:\hadoop\conf`, and ensure no files are tried to be used under `C:\Users\<user name>`

As commented, you'd have better luck running Hadoop processes in a *Linux* VM or Docker container.